# ¿Como puedo solucionar un problema al eliminar un registro?

Tags: php, android-studio

Tengo un registro que quiero eliminar estoy trabajando con android studio y web service, tengo mi base de dato ya alojado en un servidor, cuando realizo la prueba de eliminar dato marcha todo bien des el servidor, pero cuando hecho andar mi aplicación no me elimina el dato, haciendo el Debug en condicional me omite la primera condición y me manda a la segunda condición es donde tengo el mensaje de dato no eliminado, ya que tengo exactamente igual el mismo método de eliminar registros con otros formularios y ahí no tengo problemas.

**eliminar.php**

```
<?php 

    include('conexion.php');

    $codigoPro = $_POST["codigo_pro"];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM t_producto WHERE codigo_pro = '$codigoPro'";

    $result =$mysql->query($sql);

    if ($result) {
      echo "0";
    }else {
      echo "1";
   }

   $mysql->close();

  ?>
```

**Prueba realizada desde el webhost**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**método eliminar datos**

```
    private void EliminarDato(final String codigo_pro) {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(Lista_producto.this,"El dato se ha eliminado",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Lista_producto.class));
                finish();
            }else if(response.equals("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(Lista_producto.this, "Dato no eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Lista_producto.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("codigo_pro", codigo_pro);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

**Prueba Debug**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te vendría bien recoger el posible error SQL, cuando falla la query, usa $mysql->error y que lo muestre, lo escriba en un log o algo, de forma que puedas consultarlo.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP no salta ninguna error me sale en la primera condiciona que es cero como dato insertado

Comment: El error SQL no te va a saltar solo, tienes que consultarlo tú explícitamente con $mysql->error después de que el resultado de $mysql->query() se haya evaluado false:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ya aplique el error como resultado me arroja un 1

Comment: ???????? Por favor, retoca tu código en la pregunta para ver cómo recoges el posible error.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ya vi donde esta el error, elimine manualmente y me salio este error : `# 1451 - No se puede eliminar o actualizar una fila principal: falla una restricción de clave externa (`id17223682_logishuman``t_entrada_produc_albergue`, CONSTRAINT` codigo_epa` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_epa`) REFERENCIAS` t_producto` (`codigo_pro`)) ` ya que el codigo_pro es llave primary y esta relacionado con dos tres tablas mas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131357/discussion-between-jose-carlos-php-and-h-j-angel).

Comment: Ok, pues tendrás que eliminar antes los registros relacionados de las tablas hijas. Pero ese error lo puedes recuperar desde PHP, es lo que trato de decirte todo el rato.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP no me da la opcion de escribirte en el chat

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Ya corregí el error no elimine los registros de las tablas solo implemente la restricción en cascade de las tablas hijas.

Comment: Ok, estupendo :)